# VB6 to VB.NET write to random access file

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a legacy VB6 application that writes to a file in random access mode. This file is then read by an application developed by third party.

I have been tasked with rewriting the VB6 app in VB.NET however the third party application will not change. I have attempted to convert the VB6 code to VB.NET however the random access file is not being read correctly.

Provided below are condensed snippets of both the VB6 and VB.NET code. The VB.NET code is successfully writing to the file however, the field lengths are not correct and the application reading the file is not parsing the data correctly. How can I go about writing to the random access file in the same manner?

I have searched around but have not found a solution that works.

**VB6**

```
Type Person
    ID as String * 5
    Name as String * 25
    EyeColor as String * 10
End Type

Dim myPerson as Person
myPerson.ID = "13"
myPerson.Name = "Joe"
myPerson.EyeColor = "Blue"

Open <file path> For Random As <file number> Len = Len(myPerson)
    Put <file number>, myPerson.ID, myPerson
Close <file number>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Structure Person
    <VBFixedString(5)> Dim ID As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Dim Name As String
    <VBFixedString(10)> Dim EyeColor As String
End Structure

Dim myPerson as New Person
myPerson.ID = "13"
myPerson.Name = "Joe"
myPerson.EyeColor = "Blue"

FileOpen(<file number>, <file path>, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(myPerson))
    FilePut(<file number>, myPerson, myPerson.ID)
FileClose(<file number>)
```

Comment: Did you view the file with an hex editor? Maybe something with Ansi vs Unicode?

Comment: You should look at the [System.IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx) class which contains the VB.NET functions to write files instead of using the old VB6 method. You aren't very specific in what isn't working, it's hard to help. Here's a guess: You could use the [PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add extra space.

Comment: The random access files are being created and if I write and read to/from them using .net everything functions as it should. Based on my research so far, it appears to be an issue with the field lengths at the byte level. VB6 fixed field lengths are not the same as the VB.NET counterpart

Comment: What is different about the VB6 field lengths?  What encoding should the output file be?

Comment: My understanding is: in VB6, one char = 1 byte, in VB.NET, 1 char = 2 bytes. So, when a VB6 string is defined as: Name as String * 25, the string has a fixed length of 25 bytes. In .net, there is the <VBFixedString> attribute however, it does not appear to truly constrain the string.

Comment: As a follow up, the VB6 Type that is written to the random access file is 1206 bytes. The VB.NET Structure that is written is 1198 bytes. Both objects contain the same members and are defined with the same "Fixed Length Strings"....

Comment: Just guessing actually, but have you tried setting the `StringIsFixedLength` parameter to True?

Comment: @jac, thanks for the input however, the StringIsFixedLength only applies when "putting" strings. In my case I am "putting" an object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the encoding problems....

I hardcoded the FilePut RecordNumber in the test.

```
Structure Person
    <VBFixedString(5)> Dim ID As String
    <VBFixedString(25)> Dim Name As String
    <VBFixedString(10)> Dim EyeColor As String
End Structure

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myPerson As New Person
    myPerson.ID = "13".PadLeft(5)
    myPerson.Name = "Joe".PadLeft(15)
    myPerson.EyeColor = "Blue".PadLeft(10)
    Stop

    FileOpen(1, "C:\temp\random.bin", OpenMode.Random, , , Len(myPerson))
    FilePut(1, myPerson, 2) ' needs integer RecordNumber - depreciated?
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```

Visual Studio has a hex editor - I think is an option under File, Open